# Can't install lua on Mac 10.6.4

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macports, lua

I uccessfully installed MacPorts on Mac 10.6.4 but I can't install lua. I know MacPorts is installed because from my Administrator account I can successfully execute 'port selfupdate' and 'port search lua'. But when I execute 'sudo port install lua' I get errors:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bash-3.2$ sudo port install lua
--->  Computing dependencies for lua
--->  Dependencies to be installed: readline ncurses ncursesw
--->  Configuring ncursesw
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed
Log for ncursesw is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_ncursesw/main.log
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: readline ncurses ncursesw
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
bash-3.2$ 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong? Or not doing enough of?

Comment: The question was just bumped to the front page. Please provide an answer of your own ("Install developer tools") and accept it, so this question can be  considered answered.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to see what went wrong from this message alone. So far, installing port ncursesw has been unsuccessful. Run `sudo port clean ncursesw` and save the output of `sudo port -d configure ncursesw`. The `-d` is for debug and provides all the behind-the-scenes information about building a port. It might be too long to post up here, but would be helpful to see what shell command failed for you.

Comment: Thanks. I got the problem fixed. I reinstalled xcode and included the UNIX development tools which I didn't have installed before.

Comment: Great. Good to hear.